# Is Keycloak direct grant flow secured?

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, oauth, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I am wondering if Keycloak direct grant flow is secured ? I would definitely prefer login users from pages of my Angular web application and if I understand properly, to do so I have to use the [Keycloak direct grant flow](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_admin/#adding-x-509-client-certificate-authentication-to-a-direct-grant-flow).

But, this grant flow is used with `grant_type` OAuth parameter set to `password` and it seems that OAuth password grant flow is about to be deprecated with OAuth 2.1. Is it secure to use it within Keycloak ? Or should I consider it deprecated ?

Comment: I would recommend to read https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

Comment: Cheers ! Definitely good reading